# Creating a vertical separator with a label over it

Tags: html, css, forms, alignment

I've seen this somewhere before and it worked really nicely.  But I can't remember where.

Anyway, here's my desired form.

```
Enter a message:
+--------------------------------------------+
|                                            |
|                                            |
+--------------------------------------------+
                      |
                      |  Enter recipients:
                      |  +------------------+
 [Send to everyone]  OR  |                  |
                      |  +------------------+
                      |
                      |  [Send to these users]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean like on StackOverflow?

Just inspecting the DOM will tell you what you need to know: The line is an absolutely-positioned element with a left-border, and the "or" has a background colour the same as the body to cover up the line around it.

Comment: Maybe I do mean StackOverflow.  Which page are you talking about?

Comment: When you go to answer a question while not being logged in, it shows the exact layout you're asking for. Downvoter, care to explain?

Comment: That's what I was looking for!  Haters gonna hate, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

[See this jsfiddle for an example](http://jsfiddle.net/q3qtn/). The idea is you offer the user two options in the HTML...

```
<span class="screen-reader-text">Choose one of the following options:</span>
<ul>
    <li id="send-to-everyone">
        <!-- omitted -->
    </li>
    <li id="enter-recipients">
        <!-- omitted -->
    </li>
</ul>
```

...and then style the first `<li>` so it will `float:left` and have a `border-right`. Add some `:after` content to create the "or".